Flutter How to change ListTile color?
I am trying to color my tile but apparentely it doesnt work.It seems pretty easy but doesnt work.What is the problem? As far as I searched the wrapping container's color property overwrites the list tile color .What can I do?
I tried:
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: isOpen ? 5 : 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return _buildRoutineTile();
                    }),
              )

_buildRoutineTile() {
  return ListTile(
    title: Text('PLACE_HOLDER'),
    tileColor: Colors.black,
  );
}


Your ListTile code is correct. The problem is with your SingleChildScrollView. Try to remove the SingleChildScrollView and it'll work

You gave it tileColor: Colors.black, and your title is on a black-colored background. What you are trying to achieve?

@AbdulAwal it was just a place holder. I did changed the background color and didn't work.

Do you mean Scaffold background color?

After reading, another Author's Answer, I realize that my answer is not the correct one. The color ListTile one is not a problem at all Rather, it is the ListView problem with SingleChildScrollView.
There's two problems I see with the code snippets and here's my recommendation

First, remove the SingleChildScrollView widget as ListView widget already has a scrolling of its own, or you can wrap the ListView with Expanded widget
Second, please don't use Function to return a widget i.e, a helper method, rather create a Stateless or Stateful widget. The reason is that widgets has a BuildContext that Flutter can detect and compare whether to re-render (Not rebuild, a widget can be rebuild up to 60 times per sec, but it doesn't have to re-render the widget, that's where the context comes in) the widget or not after a build. A helper method rather, will be rebuild and re-render every time the parent widget is rebuild. Hence, you are wasting a lot of resource and performance. Here's the link to helper vs widget


I think it's working even though you have set a different visual properties for ListTile in the Theme, it's color is  overridden in ListTile itself.
But it seems you are missing preventing the ListView from scrolling:
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           )

That's because your provided code should give an exception.(2 nested scroll views)
or you can freely remove the SingleChildScrollView and it will work.
Hope it helps you.
